# how to bring ion icon in a input box with fixed position

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

how to bring ion icon in fix position at right side in input box where label is floating.I want only label is floating not icon icon should be in fixed position.I have tried to give position as fixed but then also it is not working.
[image]

```
<div class="input">
 <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date" id="inputdate" required>
 <label>Date<ion-icon name="calendar" item-right> 
 </ion-icon>
 </label>
</div>
```

```
$padding_input: .25em;
  $width_input_border: 1px;
  $color_form_bg: #E8F0F6;
  $time_animate: .25s;
  $color_valid: #344955;

  .input {
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: .75em;
    color: #E8F0F6;
  }
label {
    font-size:19px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: $padding_input;
    margin-left: $width_input_border;
    margin-top: -.6em;

    color: #344955;
    cursor: text; // keep it consistent

    transition: font-size $time_animate, 
      top $time_animate,
      left $time_animate,
      color $time_animate;
  }

  input {
    width: 95%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: $padding_input;
    border: 3px solid #344955;

    &:focus {
      & + label {
        color: #344955;
      }
    }

    &:valid {
      border-color: $color_valid;

      & + label {
        color: $color_valid;
      }
    }
  }
```

I want a floating input box like gmail login with floating name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want input float just change

```
position:fixed;
```

to the css class related to it , and set

```
right:#px;
bottom:#px;
```